# Snapping vertices to vertices of different plane

Tags: geometry-nodes, constraints, geometry, snapping

I am looking to create an effect where I have two planes snapped to each other, where, when one scales up on the z-axis, the other one scales down so that the sum of the two (or three, or four) always is 100%.

I've been trying to create this with simple constraints (where it follows scale but -1) but the problem is that at some point they overlap and I'm looking something that's very absolute.

How would you go about doing this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: do you want to _somehow_ realize this no matter what or which specifications/conditions have to be met and is this what you want or just a simplification of the actual setup? Do they have to be two separate objects? Do they need to be scaled or can the size be ajusted otherwise? Will this be only planes or are they gonna be replaced with other objects?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, in a way. Within my scope, this will be a 2D animation. So that it's planes isn't important either. But I want to be able to add different shaders to the two planes (in this scenario) but have them scale dependent on each other so that I can automate/animate it without having to do it manually to each plane.


The size can be adjusted otherwise. But the goal is to keep it at "full width" throughout. So that it can be fit to it's container, in a way.

Comment: @BingoBango Well, it can be important if it's planes or not and if the shaders should be simple gradients in one axis direction or if you apply image textures etc., because different outcomes might require different solutions. Even now I'm not sure if you want two separate objects because they have to be separate, or just because you want different shaders on them and don't know how to give a single object different shaders in different areas.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann My idea at the moment is that they should be one and the same gradient texture, and that scaling them up and down stretches the plane along with the shader. I guess it's hard to define for me because I also don't know what's possible, therefore I specified two separate planes because in my head that's how I will be able to manipulate and change it later. I can also see myself using a single plane duplicated in the geo-node tree.

Comment: XY problem... If I could, I would bet the first answer won't satisfy OP.

Comment: if that is the case you probably want the combined bounding box of the objects and map the position (in shader to that) abd to use the z.